# Android App submission Approval Time

Tags: android, marketplace

How long does it typically take to submit an application and get approval on the Android Marketplace?

Comment: The android market works the other way - you do not need pre-approval, but if you are found to violate the terms or do something evil, it may be taken down.

Comment: Takes 2 hours in India

Answer (score 23):

There is no approval delay: it may take up to an hour to list and be visible in search results, though. I've typically seen 15 minutes.

Comment: How about the developer submission? How does that take?

Comment: Ah, as long as it takes you to type in the text, upload your binary, provide the right screenshots/icons/images, enter pricing information. In general it depends on how prepared you are: I'd suggest creating an account and looking at the screen to get a sense of what you need.

Answer (score 5):

Submitting an App to the market(excluding the time you have to spend filling out information) is **between 15-60 minutes**. Before it was submitted and accessible within about 5 minutes but then it was not search-able. Now it takes longer but when it's done it's search-able from the start. This also applies to version updates.

The developer submission can take a couple of days until it is fully approved, sometimes they will also require you to send in documents to prove your identity and then it will take some extra time. Before, the account process didn't take any time, but I guess they added some manual control since then.

Apps: ~ 1 hour.

Dev Acc: A couple of days.

Comment: This is no longer true, as of 2015. http://techcrunch.com/2015/03/17/app-submissions-on-google-play-now-reviewed-by-staff-will-include-age-based-ratings/